# Is it possible to use ng6 Library in ng5 App?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I'm trying to import and use an ng6 Library (generated with the CLI) in an older ng5 App, but when running `ng serve` I get this error:

`WARNING in ./node_modules/pattern-library-lib/fesm5/pattern-library-lib.js
19:66-82 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'`

I used ng-packagr to build the ng6 Library and raised an issue in their repo: https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/1088

I tried commenting-out the references to these files in my services.js, but no luck.

```
// import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

// @Injectable({
//   providedIn: 'root'
// })
```

The consensus is that I can't use ng6 features in an ng5 app, which makes sense. Is it possible to somehow disable this new `providedIn` feature of `@Injectable` to let the library run?

Comment: Is upgrading not an option?

Comment: unfortunately not.

However I've made a bit of progress but am still running into packaging issues when building the library: https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library/issues/199#issuecomment-423318316